# Node.js error. Cannot understand

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error while running a simple node program:

```
/home/ubuntu/parent.js:4
    throw error;
      ^
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh: 1: node: not found

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

**parent.js :**

```
 var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
 exec('node child.js',{env: {number: 123}},function(error,stdout,stderr){ 
   if(error){ throw error; } console.log('stdout:\t',stdout); 
   console.log('stderr:\t',stderr); 
 });
```

**child.js :**

```
var number = process.env.number; 
console.log(typeof(number));
```

Comment: What command you were running?

Comment: i have two files parent.js and child.js. i am running node parent.js

Comment: can you show the content of the files and check that you have node installed correctly

Comment: Without some code, it is hard to say what is your problem.

Comment: node is installed correctly

Comment: Is "node" in your command path?  Run `which node`

Comment: /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.12/bin/node is what i get. and i have added this to the path /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.12/bin/

Comment: for me, any other simple node program is working fine

Comment: the problem isnt with node. i created another file and it worked to give the output. this is the file ::    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('ls');
child.stdout.on('data',function(data){console.log('output' + data);
});

Comment: Try with var child = spawn('bash', ['-c', 'node child.js'], {env: {number: 123}});

Answer (score 3):

When you pass these options:

```
{env: {number: 123}}
```

you're *overwriting* all of the environment variables, so it doesn't inherit your current ones.  This includes the `PATH`, which is required for it to find `node`.  You'll need to copy the current environment variables in addition to the one you want:

```
env = {};
for(key in process.env) {
  env[key] = process.env[key];
}
env.number = 123;
```

And then you use this `env` as the `env` option:

```
{env: env}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have multiple node instances you're trying to run.  To me, this doesn't look right.  You can `require('child.js')` or build your application better.

If you really want to do this, you need to understand paths.  The parent node application is running as a user, and once ran by that user, it doesn't seem to have the path to the original node file.  try exec'ing the command `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`  where `/usr/local/bin/node` exists.  If node is in `/bin`, then use that.  Find where the node executable is and add that bin directory to the path.  This has to be done on the user that node runs as.

In node, you might be able to see what PATH is available by doing

```
exec('echo $PATH')
```

each directory it's checking for is separated by colons

It would be preferable to do this outside of node, but to me this whole situation seems like it should be rethought from first concepts.